# sudo apt-get failure

Tags: command-line, updates

I was trying to `sudo apt-get update` and it spits out this errors:

```
W: Conflicting distribution: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release (expected precise-updates but got precise)
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is the P.C behind a firewall which may be blocking the proxies?

Comment: yes i was running in a VM

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: You will have to configure the VM to access the Internet. It can get a little tedious. I would suggest to take help of a IT administrator.

Comment: Can you then not connect to the internet through the terminal? Try something like `ping google.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Virtual PC then go to `Tools/Settings` on the left you will see two columns `setting and current Value`. Go to the `Networking` setting.. On the right you are now able to choose your Adapter. Open drop-down and choose your Adapter. should be the name of your Ethernet Port something like Broadcom Gigabit Ethernt etc. After that you should be able to get updates.

Hope this helps :)